# Attempt to prove that every real number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Prove that given a real number $x$, there exists a rational sequence $r_n$ such that $r_n \to x$ as $n$ grows.

Proof: Suppose $x$ is a real number. Then we know by definition, there exists a rational number such that $x < q < x + \frac1n$. Using the same argument. Then, $x < r_n < x + \frac1n$.

Can I say $x\to x$, and $x + \frac1n \to x$ as $n$ grows. Thus by the sandwich theorem, $r_n \to x$?

Or should I start with, let $\varepsilon>0$. Then we need to show $|r_n - x | < \varepsilon$?

Please any feedback/hint or anything to make it better would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: How is that "by definition"?

Comment: That is the density of rationals

Comment: That is a theorem, not a definition.

Comment: Yes. That is right. What do you think of my attempt?

Comment: I think either of those approaches is reasonable, although you've not written up complete details.  "Can I say...?": Can you give full justification for those things you want to say?  If so, yes.   Otherwise, the second approach of using the definition directly might be a better idea.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/209001/

Comment: Use Dedekind cuts

Comment: Your answer will depend on your definition of the real numbers.  What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can simply show an example of such sequence for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$:

$r_n=\dfrac{\lfloor{r\cdot10^n}\rfloor}{10^n}$, i.e., the rational number that is given by the first $n$ digits of $r$ on base $10$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Can you please elaborate on the down-vote?